# Member subobjects of zero size. Why not?

Tags: c++

This is the third question in the series of zero-size objects and subobjects today. 
The standars clearly implies that member subobjects cannot have zero size whereas base class subobjects can.

```
struct X {}; //empty class, complete objects of class X have nonzero size
struct Y:X { char c; }; //Y's size may be 1 
struct Z {X x; char c;}; //Z's size MUST be greater than 1
```

Why not allow zero-size member-subobjects JUST LIKE zero-size base-class-subobjects?

TIA

EDITING after Konrad's answer:
consider the following example:

```
struct X{}; 
struct D1:X{};
struct D2:D1, X {}; //D2 has 2 distinct subobjects of type X, can they both be 0 size and located at the same address?
```

If two base class subobjects of the same type X, as in my example, can be located at the same address, so should be able to member subobjects. If they cannot, then compiler treats this case specially and so can it treat Konrad's example(see answer below) specially and disallow zero-size member subobjects if there are multiple of the same type in the same class. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Are you aware of Boost's compressed_pair? It exists because members of zero size are disallowed. Its discussion may provide relevant insights.

Comment: @MSalters: I AM aware of Boost's compressed_pair. It DOES exist because members of zero size are disallowed. The question is why, and more precisely, which is the princpal conceptual difference between base class subobjects and member subobjects that leads to different rules for the two. Incidentally no one has yet referred to my example where two base-class subobjects of the same type are in the same derived object...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler *could* conditionally allow zero-size member objects as well as base classes, sure, but it would be more complex. The empty base class optimization *always* applies, regardless of type. Any time the compiler sees a class derive from a class with no data members, it can use the empty base class optimization.

Following @Konrad Rudolphs example through, with member objects, it'd have to check the type, verify that no other object of the same type exists at that location, and *then* maybe apply your optimization. Well, unless the member object is located at the end of the containing class. If so, then the object's "real" (non-zero) size would protrude past the end of the containing class, which would also be an error. That can never happen in the base class case because we know that the base class is located at the beginning of the derived class, and the derived class has non-zero size.

So such an optimization would be more complex, more subtle, and more likely to break in unexpected ways.

I can't cite any cases off-hand where zero-size member objects would *definitely* break, but I'm not convinced that they don't exist either. I've already pointed out a couple of limitations that don't exist in the base-class case, and most likely, more exist. So the question is, how much complexity and uncertainty should the language allow *just to make one rarely useful optimization possible*?

Comment: Do all the potential issues relate to working with the address of the member? Would they never manifest in practice if the compiler could be sure the member's address is never used? If so, then some sort of annotation hint to error if that's attempted might allow zero-size- members without causing problems. And in most cases where a zero size member might be relevant, the object's address is never needed. (You might end up passing it as this, but the method would never use it.)

Answer (score 10):

> Why not allow zero-size member-subobjects

Because then several (sub)objects of the same type could have the same address and this is *forbidden* by the standard:

```
struct X { virtual ~X() { /* Just so we can use typeid! */ } };
struct Y {
    X a;
    X b;
};

Y y;
// The standard requires that the following holds:
assert(typeid(y.a) != typeid(y.b) or &y.a != &y.b);
```

This is somewhat logical: otherwise, these two objects would be *the same* for all intents and purposes (since an object’s identity is solely determined by its type and its memory address) and declaring them separately would make no sense.

Comment: @Konrad: what if struct X{}; struct D1:X{}; struct D2:D1, X{}; Can two distinct base-class subobjects have the same address? If yes, then I'll accept your answer. If no, this means that this case is treated specially and it could be treated specially as well in case of member-subobjects

Comment: @Armen: yes, they can have the same address, since their type differs: each can be uniquely addressed via `obj.D1::some_method` vs.`obj.X::some_method` (when accessing their methods – everything else is kind of useless, since they don’t have fields). Taking their addresses is also possible and unambiguous since a pointer in C++ is strongly typed.

Comment: @Konrad: no I mean that there are 2 X subobjects in D2 in my example. Can THEY have the same address?

Comment: @Doug: You’re of course right, that would violate the assertion in my answer. Once again, I didn’t read carefully enough.

Comment: For reference, my comment was "you can't have two subobjects of the same type at the same address at the same time". I deleted it because I thought you had sorted it out :)

Comment: I am still not satisfied with the answer. If two base class subobjects of the same type, as in my example, can be located at the same address, so should be able to member subobjects. If they cannot, then compiler treats this case specially and so can it treat Konrad's example specially and disallow zero-size member subobjects if there are multiple of the same type in the same class. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry, but unless you have chapter and verse, I tend not to believe the "(sub)objects of the same type could have the same address and this is forbidden by the standard" claim. It sounds reasonable, and could have been in the standard, but I don't remember such a rule.

Comment: @MSalters: which part do you not believe? The first is a consequence of what was said before. The second part (no two objects may have the same type and address) is also a logical imperative (otherwise, objects **cannot** be identified in the context of C++). Unfortunately, I can’t find the relevant passage now but this *is* also stated in the standard. I remember reading it.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: I don't believe the logic "If subobjects could have zero size, then distinct subobjects could have the same address". That just doesn't follow logically; there could be other rules banning it. I don't believe the second part either, "the standard forbids subojects from having the same address". I don't believe there's a rule that "objects can be (uniquely) identified" either, other than _complete_ objects. Subobjects aren't complete objects, and obviously empty base subobjects cannot be uniquely identified in C++.

Comment: @MSalters: I’m baffled. Where else could consecutive objects of zero size be store, if not at the same address? If they don’t share the same address, then the whole point is that they don’t have zero storage size (even if they are logically empty). Furthermore, what makes subobjects special that they don’t have to be identifiable? Non-identifiable objects aren’t, for all intents and purposes. Empty base classes *are* uniquely identifiable in C++. Not by their storage (they don’t have any) but by their usage (namespace qualification when calling their methods, type when taking their address).

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: Obviously, at any higher address. Remember the rule that (barring access spcifiers) subobjects that are declared later have higher addresses. That's a rule that compilers still would have to follow.

Comment: @MSalters: what I meant is: my corollary is *sufficient* to require objects to have different addresses. Other rules may exist, but aren’t necessary. Different objects of the same type logically *cannot* have identical addresses. It’s not possible by definition.

Comment: @Konrad: I'm not arguing that your rules and definitions are bad, I just don't recognize them in the C++ standard.

Answer (score 2):

I think your question is good - in fact, some of the earlier articles about the empty base class optimization talk about the "empty member optimization" and specifically say that a similar optimization could apply to members. Maybe, before there was a standard, some compilers did this.

This is just idle speculation, I don't have much to back it up, but I had a look at some of these areas of the standard yesterday.

### C compatibility

In this example:

```
struct X{};
struct Y{};
struct Z {
   struct X x;
   struct Y y;
   int i;
};
```

<strike>`Z` would be a POD under C++03 rules, but would not be layout-compatible with C if `x` and `y` were zero-sized subobjects. C layout compatibility is one of the reasons for the existence of PODs. This problem can't happen with base classes because C doesn't have base classes, and classes with base classes aren't PODs in C++03, so all bets are off :).</strike>Visitor has noted that C doesn't support empty structs, in fact. So this entire argument is wrong. I'd just assumed that it did - it seemed like a harmless generalization.

Further, programs seem to assume things, like that `y` has a greater address than `x`, and stuff like that - this is guaranteed by the relational operators on pointers in 5.10/2. I don't really know if there's a compelling reason to allow this, or how many programs use  it in practice.

<strike>IMO, this is the strongest argument of all of these.</strike>

### Doesn't generalize well to arrays

Continuing the above example, add this:

```
struct Z1 {
   struct X x[1];
   struct Y y[1];
   int i;
};
```

...one might expect that `sizeof(Z1) == sizeof(Z)`, and that `x` and `y` also work as normal arrays do (i.e. that you can form a past-the-end pointer, and that pointer is different to any element's address). One of these expectations would be broken with zero-sized subobjects.

### Less compelling than the base case

One of the main reasons for deriving from an empty base is because it's a policy or interface type class. These are often empty, and requiring them to take up space would impose an "abstraction penalty", i.e. make better organized code more bloated. This is something that Stroustrup doesn't want in C++ - he wants appropriate abstraction for minimal runtime cost.

On the other hand, if you declare a member of a type, you don't inherit its functions, typedefs, etc; and you don't get the special pointer conversions from derived to base, so perhaps there's less reason to have a zero-sized member than a zero-sized base.

A counterexample here is something like the Allocator policy class in STL containers - you don't necessarily want your containers to derive from it, but you want to "keep it around" without it taking up overhead.

### Empty base class case covers most uses

...you can use private inheritance instead of declaring a member if you're worried about the space overhead. It's not quite as direct, but you can more or less achieve the same thing. Obviously this doesn't work so well if you've got lots of empty members that you would like to take up zero space.

### It's another special case

There are quite a few subtle things that don't work with this optimization. For example, you can't `memcpy` the bits of a zero-sized POD subobject into a `char` array, and then back, or between zero-sized subobjects. I've seen people implement `operator=` using `memcpy` (I don't know why...) which would break this sort of thing. Presumably it's less of a problem to break such things for base classes instead of members.

Comment: As to C compatibility, are empty structs allowed in C in the first place?

Comment: @visitor:That's a really good point. I always just assumed that they would be. Here's C99 6.7.2.1/7: `If the struct-declaration-list contains no named members, the behavior is undefined.`